# Too much vertical space after displayed math in tasks environment

Tags: line-spacing, exsheets, displaystyle, tasks

Tasks package inserts too much vertical space after displayed math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}
  \task \[ X\rule{10cm}{1pt}X \]
  \task \[ Y\rule{10cm}{1pt}Y \]
  \task \[ Z\rule{10cm}{1pt}Z \]
\end{tasks}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \[ X\rule{10cm}{1pt}X \]
  \item \[ Y\rule{10cm}{1pt}Y \]
  \item \[ Z\rule{10cm}{1pt}Z \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

What would be a proper way to fix this?

I know that I can adjust the vertical space manually with `\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}`, for example, or with a number of other hacks.  I would like to know if I am missing some configuration option, or if this behavior is somehow expected and desirable, or if this is a bug of **tasks** package.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace `\[...\]` by `$...$`, you have inline formulas. When you additionally need the behavoiur as inside `displaymath`, you can add `\displaystyle` between dollar signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}
  %\task \[ X\rule{10cm}{1pt}X \]
 \task $ Y\rule{10cm}{1pt}Y $
  %\task \[ Z\rule{10cm}{1pt}Z \]
    \task $\displaystyle Z\rule{10cm}{1pt}Z $
\end{tasks}

\begin{enumerate}
 % \item \[ X\rule{10cm}{1pt}X \]
 \item $ X\rule{10cm}{1pt}X $
  \item \[ Y\rule{10cm}{1pt}Y \]
  \item \[ Z\rule{10cm}{1pt}Z \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\displaystyle` will not make it display math. For example, it will not be numbered, centered or aligned as display math.

Comment: @Alexey a), b) etc. are also not in display math. An example, more similar to your real needs, it will be easier to guess what should be done.

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand what you mean. In my example all math was in display mode.

Comment: I do not understand what you meant by "your real needs" either...

Answer (score 2):

Another solution consists in changing the values of `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` *locally* and use the amsmath environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

{%% do not forget to chage the default values inside a group
\abovedisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\begin{tasks}
  \task\begin{gather}X\rule{10cm}{1pt}X \end{gather}
  \task \[ Y\rule{10cm}{1pt}Y \]
  \task \begin{gather} Z\rule{10cm}{1pt}Z \end{gather}
\end{tasks}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{gather}X\rule{10cm}{1pt}Y \end{gather}
  \item \begin{gather}Y\rule{10cm}{1pt}Z\end{gather}
  \item \begin{gather}Z\rule{10cm}{1pt}Y \end{gather}
\end{enumerate}
\end{subequations}
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]